# What is the adjective to describe this character of things

Tags: meaning, adjectives

I'm having difficulties trying to recall a word to describe something having consistent, unchanging properties in every part of it.
For example: a bowl of rice, every rice is roughly the same, the textures, the tastes and smells are the same. 
Every input is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You may want _homogeneous_ <<

homogeneous: consisting of parts or people that are similar to each other or are of the same type >>
[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/homogeneous).

Comment: Thank you Edwin Ashworth, this is exactly what i was looking for.